# Optimal solution to go to opposite corner of a rectangle

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid, counting

Your job is to write a program that finds the optimal number of moves it takes to get from the lower-left corner of a rectangle to the upper-right corner directly opposite.

Your program will accept input as an ordered pair `(width, height)`. These will be the dimensions of the rectangle you will work with. Your program will create an ASCII-art of the solution (use `.` for empty square and `#` for part of the solution, `X` for starting square) and count the number of moves it takes to reach the endpoint. Diagonal moves are not allowed. If there are multiple solutions, choose one to output.

The shortest program in bytes wins.

**Example**

Input: `(4, 5)`

Output:

```
..##
..#.
.##.
.#..
X#..
```

Move count: 7

Comment: So should the output contain the number of `#` in "the optimal solution" (which is any solution that never moves left or down) as well?

Comment: Re "Sorry, this is my first code-golf question so I'm not very good at making these." [Let me recommend the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can post challenge ideas and receive feedback before posting them on main. And welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, the move count is essentially the number of `#` because it's illogical to go left or down.

Comment: Is it ok to separate each char with spaces?

Comment: Do we have to output the move count AND the ascii art? How exactly should the output look like?

Comment: Nice easy question to practice `string repetition` or `nested for loop` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

Code:

```
+Í,¹<'.×'#¶J²<×'X'#¹<×J,
```

Explanation:

```
+                         # Add the length and the height.
 Í                        # Decrease by two.
  ,                       # Print this value with a newline.
   ¹<'.×                  # Take the first input, decrease by 1 and multiply with ".".
        '#¶               # Push a "#"-character and a newline character.
           J              # Join the string.
            ²<            # Take the second input and decrease by 1.
              ×           # Multiply the joined string with this value.
               'X         # Push the "X"-character.
                 '#¹<×J   # Multiply the "#"-character with (first input - 1).
                       ,  # Pop and print with a newline.
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=K8ONLMK5PCcuw5cnI8K2SsKyPMOXJ1gnI8K5PMOXSiw&input=NAo5). Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Comment: What is the difference between a byte and a character?

Comment: @KennyLau I keep forgetting to mention that in my posts... 05AB1E uses CP-1252 encoding, each character used in the code here is 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
\d+
$*.
S_`(?<=(.+)¶.*).|\D
T`.`#`.¶|.*$
:m-1=`^#
X
#
```

Takes input separated by a linefeed and outputs the solution grid followed by the move count.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqLgpTX2AoPzw9KC4rKcK2LiopLnxcRApUYC5gI2AuwrZ8LiokCjptLTE9YF4jClgKIw&input=NQo1)

#### Explanation

```
\d+
$*.
```

Turn both integers into that many `.`s, i.e. convert them to unary.

```
S_`(?<=(.+)¶.*).|\D
```

This builds a grid of `.`s, by matching each `.` in the unary height and capturing the unary representation of the width. The `S` activates split mode which returns the captured strings, and the `|\D` and `_` together ensure that everything else is removed from the string.

```
T`.`#`.¶|.*$
```

This turns the last character of each line as well as the entire last line into `#`s.

```
:m-1=`^#
X
```

This uses a ton of options to convert only the first `#` on the last row to `X` (we need to make sure that only the last row is affected because of width-1 inputs). `m` activates multi-line mode which makes `^` match the beginning of lines. `-1=` tells Retina to perform the substitution only on the last match. Finally, `:` switches off the default silent mode such that the grid is printed to STDOUT as an intermediate result.

```
#
```

Finally, we simply count the number `#` in the string, which corresponds to the number of moves.

Comment: Maybe a built in should be added to retina for converting to unary.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 26 bytes

```
DtQ+RtF; Q\.*t\#+)\X\#Qt*+
```

[Try it here](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=DtQ%2BRtF%3B+Q.*t%5C%23%2B%29%5CX%5C%23Qt*%2B&input=4%0A5)

---

Or a noncompetitive 34 bytes, add apply node with an ast)

```
jUa]Dm!X|RZjht]q+".#X"R@)Fs
);jmts
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=jUa]Dm!X|RZjht]q%2B%22.%23X%22R%40%29Fs%0A%29%3Bjmts&input=%284%2C6%29)

Or 30 bytes if allowed spaces as padding

```
jUa]Dm!X|RZjht]q+".#X"R@)Pjmts
```

Comment: Why is it non-competitive?

Comment: I changed the language after the challenge was posted

Comment: @muddyfish Internal server error when you click try it here

Comment: @Insane fixed the bug (hopefully) The internal test for time was failing whenever the day changed.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>32</s> <s>29</s> 24 bytes

```
AtMQVH+*\.G\#;+\X*\#G+GH
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AtMQVH%2B*%5C.G%5C%23%3B%2B%5CX*%5C%23G%2BGH&input=%284%2C+5%29&debug=0)

Sample input:

```
(4, 5)
```

Sample output:

```
...#
...#
...#
...#
X###
7
```

How it works:

```
AtMQVH+*\.G\#;+\X*\#G+GH
                           assign('Q',eval_input())
AtMQ                       assign('[G,H]',Pmap(lambda d:tail(d),Q))
    VH       ;             for N in range(H):
      +*\.G\#                  implicit_print(plus(times(".",G),"#"))
              +\X*\#G      implicit_print(plus("X",times("#",G)))
                     +GH   implicit_print(plus(G,H))
```

---

Previous attempt:

```
JthQK@Q1+*++*\.J\#btK+\X*\#Jt+JK
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JthQK%40Q1%2B*%2B%2B*%5C.J%5C%23btK%2B%5CX*%5C%23Jt%2BJK&input=%284%2C+5%29&debug=0)

Sample input:

```
(4, 5)
```

Sample output:

```
...#
...#
...#
...#
X###
7
```

How it works:

```
JthQK@Q1+*++*\.J\#btK+\X*\#Jt+JK
                                 assign('Q',eval_input())        --Q is now an official pair of numbers (4, 5)
JthQ                             assign("J",decrement(first(Q))) --gets the first element, and then take 1 from it, and assign it to J
    K@Q1                         assign("K",lookup(Q,1))         --K is now the second element (count from 0) of the pair.
        +            +\X*\#J     concat(-----------------------------------------------------------,concat("X",times("#",J)))
         *         tK                   repeat(--------------------------------------,decrement(K))
          +       b                            concat(-------------------------,"\n")
           +    \#                                    concat(-------------,"#")
            *\.J                                             repeat(".",J)
                            t+JK decrement(add(J,K)) <--- auto-print
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner Maybe you could help me golf this?

Comment: @KennyLau I don't know any Pyth...

Comment: @MartinBüttner It's quite embarrassing for Pyth to be defeated, right

Comment: You can combine the first two assignments with `AtMQ`.  This assigns the two values to `G` and `H`.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
q~\(_2$(+p'.*a*'#f+)W%_"X#"era+N*
```

Takes input in the form `width height` and outputs the move count on the first line, followed by the solution grid.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%5C(_2%24(%2Bp'.*a*'%23f%2B)W%25_%22X%23%22era%2BN*&input=4%205)

This also works for the same byte count:

```
q~\('.*a*'#f+)W%_"X#"era+N*_'#e=p
```

Comment: Haven't seen a CJam solution in a while.

Comment: @Cyoce [You need to look harder.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=cjam+is%3Aa) ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 48 bytes

This is an anonymous function, which according to [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6912/15599) is acceptable unless the question states "full program." I wouldn't normally be pedantic about this but the problem is very simple and doing a program would be a significant % increase to the score.

Input is two arguments. Return value is an array containing the ASCII art string and the number of `#` in the path.

```
->w,h{[(?.*(w-=1)+'#
')*(h-=1)+?X+?#*w,w+h]}
```

**In test program**

```
f=->w,h{[(?.*(w-=1)+'#
')*(h-=1)+?X+?#*w,w+h]}

puts f[4,5]
```

**Output**

```
...#
...#
...#
...#
X###
7
```

It's just a string of h-1 rows of w-1 dots, followed by a `#` and newline. I put the `#` at the end in order to use a single `#\n` literal for both `#` and newline (the code contains an actual newline rather than an escape sequence.) The final row is then an `X` followed by w-1 `#`'s.

It was shorter to decrement the values of w and h during the ASCII art generation, so that the final calculation is simply `w+h`.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
+qq35IMwX"46 5Lt4$(88HG(c
```

*EDIT (June 10, 2016): the link below includes a modification ( `5L` is replaced by `IL`) to adapt to changes in the language*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=K3FxMzVJTXdYIjQ2SUx0NCQoODhIRyhj&input=NAo1)

#### Explanation

```
+       % take two inputs. Add them
qq      % subtract 2
35      % push ASCII for '#'
IMw     % push the two inputs again. Swap them
X"      % 2D char array of '#'  repeated as indicated by inputs
46      % push ASCII for '.'
5Lt4$(  % fill all but last and row columns with that
88HG(   % fill 88 (ASCII for 'X') at linear index given by second input
c       % convert to char
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```js
w=>h=>--w+--h+`
${"."[r="repeat"](w)}#`[r](h)+`
X`+"#"[r](w)
```

### Usage

```
f(4)(5)

7
...#
...#
...#
...#
X###
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>137</s> 132 bytes

```java
w->h->{String s="";int i=0,j;for(;i<h;i++){for(j=1;j<w;j++)s+=".";s+="#\n";}s+="X";for(j=1;j<w;j++)s+=".";s+="\n"+(w+h-2);return s;}
```

Comment: Java isn't exactly a joke though...

Comment: s+= instead of s=s+ will save you a couple bytes

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 118 bytes

```
(w:Int,h:Int)=>{print(Array.fill(h-1,w-1)('.')map(new String(_))mkString("","#\n","#\nX"));Seq.fill(w-1)(print("#"))}


(w:Int,h:Int)=>{...}           //define a function with 2 Ints as parameters
print(                        //print ...   
  Array.fill(h-1,w-1)('.')    //an array of arrays with dimensions (h-1,w-1)
                              //and fill it with a dot
  map(new String(_))          //map each inner array of chars to a string
  mkString("","#\n","#\nX")   //create a string from the array, with
                              //an empty string before the array,
                              //"#\n" as a seperator between the elements
                              //and "#\nX" at the end   
);
Seq.fill(w-1)(print("#"))     //w-1 times print "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 64 bytes

```
c!n=c<$[2..n]
w#h=unlines$('.'!w++"#")!h++['X':'#'!w,show$w+h-2]
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStr $ 4 # 5
...#
...#
...#
...#
X###
7
```

How it works:

```
c!n = c <$ [2..n]                       -- helper function: make (n-1) copies of c

                                        -- main function
                     !h                 -- (h-1) times
       ('.'!w ++ "#")                   --    (w-1) dots and a hash sign
                       ++[      ,     ] -- followed by
                          'X' : '#'!w   --    an 'X' and (w-1) hash signs
                            show$w+h-2  --    and the number of steps
unlines                                 -- join everything with newlines in-between
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 81 bytes

[Try it online!](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

Golfed:

```
w,h=(...)print((("."):rep(w-1).."#\n"):rep(h-1).."X"..("#"):rep(w-1))print(w+h-2)
```

Ungolfed:

```
w,h=4,5
print((("."):rep(w-1).."#\n"):rep(h-1).."X"..("#"):rep(w-1))
print(w+h-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 48.

```
lambda w,h:('.'*(w-1)+'#\n')*(h-1)+'X'+'#'*(w-1)
```

To use it, add `f=` before the line above and call it like this:

```
f(4, 5)
```

Result:

```
...#
...#
...#
...#
X###
```